# Composite Primary Key of which one field is a DATETIME data type

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have the following table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointment` (
  `idappointment` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `appdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `appnote` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Please enter a relevant note',
  `chair_idchair` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idappointment`,`chair_idchair`),
  KEY `fk_appointment_chair_idx` (`chair_idchair`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

Typical values for the `appdate` field are:
`2013-07-05 08:30:00` and
`2013-07-05 09:00:00`
so no timestamp values and all appointments differ with a fixed time interval.

For my application I need to ensure that no single chair is double booked at the same time interval, for this reason I thought of creating a composite primary key consisting of the `appdate` field and the `chair_idchair` field and then setting this composite primary key to unique.

My question is how would one do this in MySQL and more importantly is it actually the best way to ensure that no double bookings can be booked from the DB's side. I don't want to just rely on the app to do this checking as users will be booking from multiple locations concurrently.

Comment: Cheers, just a side-note: "then setting this composite primary key to unique" -- primary keys are unique by definition. (Just for curious googlers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a composite primary key containing `appdate` and `chair_idchair` will not solve the problem. If appdate for one entry if `2013-07-05 08:30:00` then it will allow another entry with appdate `2013-07-05 08:31:00` for the same chair id, which is incorrect.

To overcome this, before inserting any entry, you will need to check if there is any appointment whose time is overlapping with the current appointment by a query and then only you should allow insert.

E.g. if the duration of an appointment is 30 mins then, before inserting any appointment, you will have to check whether there is any appointment for the same chair whose time is less than 30 mins of the new appointment time.

`TIMEDIFF()` function of mysql may help you in this.

Answer (score 0):

As Darshan noted, a composite index like this will not enforce uniqueness on `appdate`.
You would be better off using the autoincrement column for a PK. And add another index on `appdate` (unique if necessary).

This way it will be as easy to implement, and when your customer decides that you will need to have 2 records with the same `appdate` in the database it will be easier to change too.

If you want to enforce `appdate` uniqueness via the database you can create a before insert/update trigger to normalize the value of `appdate` (for example - converting it from `2013-07-05 12:33:41' to`2013-07-05 12:30:00`). And then put a unique constraint with the index.